# Convert list of complex objects to Map using Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have an array of subjects

```
List<String> subjects = Arrays.asList(“physics”, “maths”);
```

I wanted to create a dummy list of users for each of these subjects and add them to a map with key as subject and value as List

Something like

```
Map<String,List<User>> userMap = new HashMap<>();
for(String subject: subjects){
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        User user = new User(“first name”+i+subject,”last name”+i+subject);
        users.add(user);
    } 
    userMap.put(subject,users);
}
```

I wanted to try this with the Java 8. Just tried something below, but doesn’t look like the right way.

```
subjects.stream().map((subjectName)->{
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        User user = new User(“first name”+i+subject,”last name”+i+subject);
        userList.add(user);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
subjects.stream()
        .map(subjectName -> {
            List<User> users = .... create the users;
            return new SimpleEntry<>(subjectName, users);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue))
```

This would be one way if you *really* wanted to do it with `java-8` and streams. One improvement would be to have a method that takes a `String subjectName` and create that `Entry` for example:

```
private static Entry<String, List<User>> createEntry(String subjectName) {
    List<User> users = .... create the user;
    return new SimpleEntry<>(subjectName, users);
}
```

And use it with:

```
subjects.stream()
        .map(YourClass::createEntry)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue))
```

Just notice that your loop *is* the cleanest way to do it IMO

Comment: …or just use `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), subjectName -> { 
 List<User> users = .... create the users;  return users;  }))` without a preceding `map` step.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it with java 8:

```
Map<String,List<User>> userMap = new HashMap<>();

subjects.forEach(s -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        userMap.computeIfAbsent(s, k -> new ArrayList<>())
            .add(new User("first name" + i + subject, "last name" + i + subject));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this one step at a time.  First, the inner loop for creating 10 users can be written with streams as:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;


List<User> userList = IntStream.range(0, 10)
    .mapToObj(i -> new User("first name" + i + subject, "last name" + i + subject)
    .collect(toList());
```

And the outer loop can be written as

```
subjects.stream()
    .collect(toMap(
        subject -> subject,   // key for the map is the subject
        subject -> ...        // whatever should be the value of the map
    ));
```

And now we can put it together:

```
Map<String, List<User>> userMap = subjects.stream()
        .collect(toMap(
                subject -> subject,
                subject -> IntStream.range(0, 10)
                        .mapToObj(i -> new User("first name" + i + subject, "last name" + i + subject))
                        .collect(toList())
        ));
```

Comment: This is much simple!! :-)